# jboss as 7 can't deploy my project, persistence issue

Tags: jboss7.x

it says this in the failed war

> {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps
>   that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services"
>   => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"feb27.war#TAPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit.\"feb27.war#TAPU\": Failed
>   to start service"}}}}

```
standalone -b PCNAME C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.CR1b\bin Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.CR1b\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.CR1b

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M  -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000  -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman  -server

===============================================================================

16:11:55,450 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.0.CR6 16:11:55,738 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.1.GA 16:11:55,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBoss AS 7.1.0.CR1b "Flux Capacitor" starting 
    16:11:56,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as] Creating http management service using  socket-binding (management-http) 
16:11:56,781 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.0.CR7 
16:11:56,793 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.0.CR7 16:11:56,804 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.0.CR8 
16:11:56,822 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log han dlers 16:11:56,843 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 30) JBAS010300: Activating Infinispan subsystem. 
16:11:56,873 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408:  Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.6.Final) 
16:11:56,901 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) Activating Security Subsystem 
16:11:56,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS0 11800: Activating Naming Subsystem 
16:11:56,921 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) Picketbox version=4.0.6.Beta2 
16:11:56,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension 
16:11:56,943 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011 910: Activating OSGi Subsystem 
16:11:56,983 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: St arting Naming Service 
16:11:57,000 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-2) Binding JAXR ConnectionFactory: java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory 
16:11:57,001 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerServic e Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Dr iver (version 1.3) 16:11:57,136 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS01 5400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default] 
16:11:57,185 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.0.GA 
16:11:57,303 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) Listening on  /127.0.0.1:4447 
16:11:58,177 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) Listening on  /127.0.0.1:9999 
16:11:58,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss-as-7 .1.0.CR1b\standalone\deployments 
16:11:58,304 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thr ead 1-5) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080 
16:11:58,364 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS] 
16:11:58,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss AS 7.1.0.CR1b " Flux Capacitor" started in 3138ms - Started 131 of 201 services (68 services are  passive or on-demand) 
16:11:58,392 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting deployment of "feb27.war" 
16:11:58,968 INFO  [org.jboss.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for TAPU 
16:11:59,035 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC0000 1: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."feb27.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."feb27.war".POST
    _MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "feb27.war"
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(Deplo ymentUnitPhaseService.java:121) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.CR1b.jar:7.1.0.CR1b]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(Se rviceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceCont rollerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [:1 .7.0_03]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:
    1.7.0_03]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_03] Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBA S011093: Could not load component class org.springframework.web.context.ContextL oaderListener
            at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.pr ocessComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:113)
            at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.de ploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:54)
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(Deplo ymentUnitPhaseService.java:115) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.CR1b.jar:7.1.0.CR1b]
            ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.Con textLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.feb27.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java: 190)
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(Con currentClassLoader.java:468)
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(Concu rrentClassLoader.java:456)
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentCl assLoader.java:398)
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoad er.java:120)
            at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.pr ocessComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:111)
            ... 7 more

    16:11:59,052 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015 856: Undeploy of deployment "feb27.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"feb27.war\".POST_MODULE " => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"fe b27.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"feb27 .war\""}} 16:11:59,259 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Stopped deployment feb27.war in 205ms 
16:11:59,261 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBA S014774: Service status report JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:    service jboss.deployment.unit."feb27.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss. deployment.unit."feb27.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "feb27.war"


16:11:59,265 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-t hreads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2"
=> {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jbos s.deployment.unit.\"feb27.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartExce ption in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"feb27.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to proc ess phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"feb27.war\""}}}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that your war file references a (yet) unknown jdbc driver or data source

Also you seem to lack some dependencies:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_03] 
  Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: 
  JBAS011093: Could not load component class 
  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```